# Crystal report Signature is there any way to use electronics signed or good quality of transperancy

Tags: crystal-reports, signature

Crystal report Signature
Is there any way to add e-signature to report or good quality transparency image in crystal report? Or the latest version can support now ? Or is there a DLL that helps the image to be sharper?

Crystal report 2016 i try to use .swf or other but crystal report still convert picture to low quality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: make sure the default or specified printer can handle high resolution. Crystal renders content based on the printer driver (even if you are not printing).

Option 2: If this is a color issue, go to ***File, Report Options...*** and turn on the option to '***Retain Original Color Depth***'

[image]

Option 3: if the issue is with an application using the Crystal Runtime, there is a code option to switch from ***Normal*** draw mode to ***HighQualityBicubic***. I have that option in my Crystal viewer application and it makes a significant difference for certain situations.

Option 4: if you can deliver the content as PDF, there are Crystal Reports automation tools that can export the report to a pdf and immediately also add images and/or digital signatures to the pdf.

Comment: This could help a lot. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder the OPTION #3: where we can edit Code Option?